# Downloading 15gb+ worth of emails from gmail via imap without triggering account suspension

Tags: email, gmail, imap, google-workspace

Im switching my email client (from mac mail to airmail) ive got a gmail account i want to move over this account is running on Google Apps for Business and is c. 15gb in size.

I want to setup this account and download all the messages and attachments to my new mail client, the issue with this is the account can become suspended when it reaches a limit and takes up to 24hr to reset.

Is there a method were I can download the data in a way that wont trigger the gmail account suspension ?

---

Some further reading on the topic :

[Google bandwidth limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518?hl=en)

You also seem to be able to reset limits in a Google apps for business account according to [this article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2789146?hl=en), but Im on the legacy free version.

---

If you think this question is better suited in another SO forum please let me know i could decide between SuperUser and WebApps

Comment: If you're using mac mail now, does it already have a local copy of all your mail? Can you import it from mac mail, instead of downloading another copy? Or if it's imap-only now, keep using it like that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tired using google takeout to just get a copy of the majority of your data, create the new account and then add existing account so it only has to sync a small bit?

Takeout:
https://www.google.com/settings/takeout

Support:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?source=gsearch